# Splunk query for matching lines that do not contain text

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

To find logging lines that contain "gen-application" I use this search query :

```
source="general-access.log" "*gen-application*"
```

How to amend the query such that lines that do not contain "gen-application" are returned ?

source="general-access.log" != "*gen-application*" returns error :

```
Error in 'search' command: Unable to parse the search: Comparator '!=' has an invalid term on the left hand side:
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use the `NOT` operator.

```
source="general-access.log" NOT "*gen-application"
```

Keep in mind that Splunk also has support for `AND` and `OR`.